# Why are my colors shifting when exporting a gif in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, color-spaces

You can see how the colors got very dull compared to the original. I've tried changing number of colors, color space, dithering. I tried locking or shifting colors in the color table. Nothing seems to work.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what's going on there, but try selecting one of the presets, such as "GIF 128 Dithered", then change the number of colours to 256.

Comment: tried a few different presets but just does some minor changes. Color is still washed out.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem unfortunately. What colour mode is the original in?  RGB? 8bit/channel? Does it do this with other images, or only for this specific one? Have you tried restarting Photoshop, restarting your computer, or resetting your preferences?

Comment: Actually, it's only the red that seems to be changing that much. Most likely to unify the table.

Comment: Interesting, it does seem to only be the red channel. I tried with another gif that had red and same thing happened but less pronounced. Maybe something to do with amount of red or other colors? Then tried with one without any red and it looked great. Something wrong with red channel somehow. It's sRGB, 8 bit/channel.

Comment: I tried shifting the red using the color picker but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I think that particular red may be close enough to skin tones, that the attempt to unify the table is forcing it to a more brown tone. I'd *try* making the original red way, way, way, more vibrant and pronounced (even unnaturally so). Of course, you could always find those color sin the color table and manually try reassigning them, but that may be more trouble.

Comment: I think you're right. I cranked up the red to fire engine and it changed the color of the skin and hair too.

Comment: What happens if you open that screenshot & try to export it? Is the effect cumulative?